# How to build a class in C++ to use in Python?

Tags: python, c++, module, python-c-api

`PyMethodDef` from `Python.h` allows to specify Cpp-built functions to use in `Python`. However, there is much doubt if this can be applied for Cpp-built classes and I can't find anything like `PyClassDef` which could presumably help me to do so. All I've managed to find concerns class methods, but not the class itself. Is it possible to build a class in `C++` with regular `Python-C-API` to use as a regular class in `Python`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pybind11 to implement python call c++ native class.
Link here [pybind11 class](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/classes.html)
it's easier use than cpython.

Comment: That's a option indeed, but is there a way to implement it using standard `python-c-api`? I just haven't got familiar with `pybind11` yet :) If no, well I should learn it

Comment: @Kaiyakha IMHO it is much easier to use something like `Boost.Python`, `Cython`  or `pybind11` instead of dealing with everything these tools take care of for you ...

Comment: @fxweidinger since I have just started learning `python-c-api`, it's reasonable to mess around with basic things to better understand how it works, isn't it?

Comment: @Kaiyakha it obviously depends on your use case and the work you can put into it. This [tutorial](https://intermediate-and-advanced-software-carpentry.readthedocs.io/en/latest/c++-wrapping.html#manual-wrapping) might be of use to you.

Comment: @fxweidinger OK it's clear there are better means. But back to the muttons, can I build a class using specifically regular `python-c-api`?

Comment: @Kaiyakha I think if you want to write fairly regular C++ classes and syntax Boost.Python is the way to go. If you're willing to deal with nasty syntax and `PyObject` look at [this](https://bertvandenbroucke.netlify.app/2019/11/20/exposing-c++-to-python-an-introduction/) , scroll down to heading "Python C API"

Comment: @fxweidinger well there is nothing about classes in regular `python-c-api` though

Comment: pybind11 is wrapper of python-c-api, you can learn it from pybind11 source code if you need. CPython haven't a c++ class wrapper, so you need implement a python class to wrap c++ class use native CPython.

Comment: @cepin _CPython haven't a c++ class wrapper, so you need implement a python class to wrap c++ class use native CPython._ Now we're talking, that's the answer I've been waining for! You can add this to your answer and I'll accept it. Someone else may be wondering about the issue later

Comment: @Kaiyakha Ah well, I think the wording of your question was a little misleading to me. But good to know, you found what you were looking for.

Comment: @fxweidinger I guess I should've specified the way I wanted to wrap a cpp class. Added that to the question already